# GIT bash : permission denied

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to set clone GIT directory and then installing virtual env in my machine which is running python. This is for installing learning game per below link.

https://opensource.com/article/20/5/python-games

I'm able to execute below two commands in GIT bash and clone this.

> $ git clone https://github.com/moshez/penguin-bit-by-bit.git

> $ cd penguin-bit-by-bit

But when I'm executing below command in GIT, its giving me permission denied error

> python -m venv venv

[image]

looks to be permission issues. But help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: How did you install python? The version provided by the Windows Store is conflicting with the installed one (if you have an installed one). Try running `python3` instead of python, and if that does not work, a simple solution is to simply install python from the windows store (you could also try playing with your PATH environment variable).

Comment: I installed from anaconda and its 3.7.8. I tried from python3 command as well but same message.

Comment: I change env variable as well and its same issue

Comment: installed latest python 3.8 and still same thing...not sure why permission denied

Comment: have you tried installing the Windows Store version? just open a cmd session and type python and it will open the installation page for you.

Comment: juts able to finish looks like some I was using different CLI but actually need to do in anaconda CLI and it fixed

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. But, when I tried:

```
py -m venv venv
```

instead of

```
python -m venv venv
```

It worked.